# Can't reload UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

I am trying to design View where i can show elements in sync with my Firebase Database. Every time element in my array changes it gets duplicated. Tried to use

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

but nothing changes. Tried as well

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray.init(object: indexPath) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

and it didn't work as previously.
I have tried unsuccesfully to perform reloading tableView in main thread using function

```
performSelectorOnMainThread
```

I am posting my code for you guys so someone can help me. Im quite new to iOS programming and i can't figure out when to reload data in tableView. Even after reading Apple's Documentation.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Akcja", message: "Wybierz akcję", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let changeFieldNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Zmień numer boiska", style: .Default, handler: {(action) in

        self.showAlertOfChangingFieldNumber(indexPath)

    })

    let sendToRefereeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Wskaż sędziego", style: .Default, handler: {(action) in
        //self.championshitTournamentMode = false

    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Anuluj", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(changeFieldNumberAction)
    alert.addAction(sendToRefereeAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showAlertOfChangingFieldNumber(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let fieldNumberAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Numer boiska", message: "Wpisz numer boiska", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    fieldNumberAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Numer boiska"
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    })

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Zapisz", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

        let fieldNumberTextField = fieldNumberAlert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let fieldNumber = Int(fieldNumberTextField.text!)
        self.updateGameFieldNumber(fieldNumber!, indexPath: indexPath)
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Anuluj", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    fieldNumberAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
    fieldNumberAlert.addAction(saveAction)

    self.presentViewController(fieldNumberAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func updateGameFieldNumber(fieldNumber: Int, indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let gameKey = games[indexPath.row].key
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("games").child(gameKey)

    games[indexPath.row].fieldNumber = fieldNumber
    ref.updateChildValues(games[indexPath.row].toAnyObject() as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
    //self.games.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row+1)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray.init(object: indexPath) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

And my tableView delegate functions and function made for filling my array based on Firebase's database looks like that:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCellTableViewCell

    if games[indexPath.row].fieldNumber == 0 {
        cell.fieldNumberLabel.text = "-"
    } else {
        cell.fieldNumberLabel.text = String(games[indexPath.row].fieldNumber)
    }
    cell.firstParticipantLabel.text = games[indexPath.row].firstParticipant

    cell.secondParticipantLabel.text = games[indexPath.row].secondParticipant

    cell.gameImage.image = UIImage(named: "tenisBall")

    if games[indexPath.row].completed != true {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 109.0/255, blue: 95.0/255, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 160/255, green: 1, blue: 86/255, alpha: 1)
    }

    return cell

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.games.count
}

func getGames() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("games")

    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let gameItem = GameItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            if(gameItem.tournamentName == self.tournamentName) {
                self.games.append(gameItem)
            }

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Comment: This is a straightforward scenario. For starters, you should simply be able to call self.tableView.reloadData().

If that is not working, then you have a more fundamental problem that will not be solved by using .reloadRowsAtIndexPath or performSelectorOnMainThread.

Comment: What do your cellForRowAtIndexPath, numnerOfSections, and numberOfRowsInSection functions look like?

Comment: @MikeTaverne i have edited my post so you can see what is going on inside tableView delegate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets duplicated because instead of updating the value in your "games" array, you append the modified value to the array. This happens in the "getgames()" method.

Comment: I know i am appending the array, but it happens only once when controller is loaded. After your suggestion i have added a function to remove any duplicated from array before refreshing the tableView.

Comment: Perhaps it is more efficient if you check if the game is already present in the array in your observation block. If it is, update it, if not append. In that way the first time every game will be added, and when the block gets automatically called for update, it does not append any data you will have to remove afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I have used `contains` property of array to check if the game is already present. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

inside the

```
func getGames()
```

after

```
    self.games.append(gameItem)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```